# Long prediction time when using converter.optimization in a VGG16 model and Tensorflow lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I wrote a model that is based on VGG16 and I just only added two additional convolution layers. The output is an array of size 16x16x1 which is just the result of simple binary classification. I used TensorFlow-lite and the code is based on the documentation available. The problem is that when I'm making a prediction using the model it takes a looong time (near 5 mins) to give me the result.
I'm using Tensorflow 2.4 on GPU, Python 3.7, my graphics card is GTX 1660Ti (mobile version) and the CPU is intel i7 9750H.
The code is available below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
import keras
import pathlib

saved_model_dir= 'model/'
saved_modelh5 = 'model.h5'
dataset_path = 'bound box dataset/img'
out_path = 'converted_model.tflite'
num_calibration_steps = 10


#-----------------------------------------------------------
images = []
for file in os.listdir(dataset_path):
    img = cv2.imread( os.path.join(dataset_path,file) )
    images.append(img)
images = np.array( images )

imgs_tensor = tf.cast( images, dtype = tf.float32)/255.0
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((imgs_tensor)).batch(1)
print('data loaded')

#-----------------------------------------------------------
def representative_dataset_gen():
  for input_value in ds.take(num_calibration_steps):
    yield [input_value]




#converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(keras.models.load_model(saved_modelh5))  
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT ]
#converter.representative_dataset = tf.lite.RepresentativeDataset( representative_dataset_gen )
#converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
tflite_model = converter.convert()


#------------------------------------------------------------
#with open(out_path, "wb")as f:
#    f.write(tflite_model)
print('converted')
tflite_model_file = pathlib.Path(out_path)
tflite_model_file.write_bytes(tflite_model)
print('Saved')



img = cv2.imread('bound box dataset/img/1.png')
input_data = img.reshape(1,512,512,3).astype(np.float32)/255.0

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter( model_content = tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test model on random input data.
t = time.time()
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
#input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

t = time.time() - t
print('predict time:',t)
```

Comment: Ok, so I found out something new. When I initialize the `converter.optimizations` or the `converter.representative_dataset`, the prediction time rises up to like 5 minutes. But when I leave them uninitialized, the prediction drops down to just about a second. Any idea why?

Comment: Theres something else, I'm using Windows 10 and it's updated to the last version. Do you think that switching to a Linux base os will have any effect on it?

Answer (score 0):

First your GPU is not calculating this prediction. You have to use cuda to tranfer data to the gpu, but that is not neccesary here.

1. **Reshape** your images to (256,256) or even lower, with a size of (512, 512) the image is very times big for the VGG input. This is why your computations are taking so long.
2. My next advise would be to change to a newer architecture like ResNet50.